# What's a good implementation of applying a unary function to some elements of a vector?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, std

I'd like to apply a function `UnaryFunction f` to some elements of a std container, given a predicate `UnaryPredicate p` - sort of what you would get if you combine [`std::partition`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition) and then apply [`std::for_each`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) to one of the partitions.

I'm quite new to C++, so forgive my ignorance. I have, however, looked for a suitable implementation in `<algorithm>`, yet I can't seem to find the desired function.

Based on the possible implementations over at [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/), I've come up with the following:

```
template<class InputIt, class UnaryPredicate, class UnaryFunction>
UnaryFunction for_each_if(InputIt first, InputIt last, UnaryPredicate p, UnaryFunction f)
{
    for (; first != last; ++first) {
        if (p(*first))
        {
            f(*first);    
        }        
    }
    return f;
}
```

The return value is modeled as per `std::for_each`, although an [`OutputIter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/OutputIterator) might have been a  better choice. This would require a more convoluted implementation though, and so I've chosen brevity over finesse this time around. The alternative implementation is left as an exercise to the reader.

My question is: is there already an established way to do this in the std library? If not, would this be a reasonable implementation of such a function template?

Comment: Why don't you use std::partition followed by std::for_each (operating on range based on returned iterator from partition)?

Comment: There isn't such an algorithm in std lib. You can combine `std::for_each` and `boost::filter_iterator`, however.

Comment: Doesn't look like `algorithm` has a function like what you are looking for. I would use the name `for_each_if`.

Comment: user2672165: Good question. Two reasons, actually. First, the container is shared, and may not get re-ordered. Second, because it will be faster than what you suggest.

Comment: Then can't you just encapsulate the predicate into the function? I mean creating a new function containing both f and p.

Comment: Ehm ... yup. That's obviously a good way. (Facepalm). :)

Comment: if OP have no problem with (header only) dependencies, you may be interested in LINQ for C++. There is a link on isocpp.org some weeks ago: [here](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/linq-like-list-manipulation-in-c/240166882?pgno=1) and [here](http://cpplinq.codeplex.com/)

Comment: CodeSettler: I don't have a problem with dependencies, although in my current project I guess I'd rather not. Thanks for bringing LINQ for C++ to my attention, though! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

STL does not support composition of algorithms very well. As you said, you could first call `partition`, and then call `for_each` on one of the partitions if you don't care about the order of elements.

For a new project, or one where you can introduce libraries, I would strongly recommend to have a look at a range library, e.g. Boost.Range or [Eric Niebler's range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3).

With the range library, it can be done like this:

```
template<typename R, typename P, typename F> 
F for_each_if(R& rng, P pred, F f)
{ 
    using namespace boost::adaptors;

    return (rng | filtered(pred) | for_each(f));
}
```

Comment: Any recommendation for Range v3 gets an upvote from me. Note, however, that it requires `constexpr` (and very likely expression SFINAE) so current releases of VC++ can't use it. (BTW, the function should be named `for_each_if`, as `f` may be non-mutating.)

Comment: Thanks Jens! I've never used this part of Boost, and most definitely not range-v3. Thanks for bringing it to my attention!

Answer (score 1):

As far as the comments go, there seems to be no implementation of this in the std library. However, as user2672165 points out, the predicate may be easily included in the function. To illustrate this, see the following modified version of the [`for_each` example over at cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each):

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

struct Sum {
    Sum() { sum = 0; }
    void operator()(int n) { sum += n; }

    int sum;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> nums{3, 4, 2, 9, 15, 267};

    std::cout << "before: ";
    for (auto n : nums) {
        std::cout << n << " ";
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    std::for_each(nums.begin(), nums.end(), [](int &n){ if (n > 5) n++; });

    // Calls Sum::operator() for each number
    Sum s = std::for_each(nums.begin(), nums.end(), Sum());

    std::cout << "after:  ";
    for (auto n : nums) {
        std::cout << n << " ";
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
    std::cout << "sum: " << s.sum << '\n';
}
```

Here, the predicate is added to the function, so that `[](int &n){ n++; }` now becomes `[](int &n){ if (n > 5) n++; }` to only apply the function to integer elements greater than 5.

Expected output is

```
before: 3 4 2 9 15 267 
after:  3 4 2 10 16 268 
sum: 303
```

Hope this helps someone else out there.